# What is the Difference Between Wait until Visible and Wait until Located in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am using both `wait(until.elementLocated(element, timeout))` and `wait(until.elementVisible(element, timeout))`. The 'wait until visible' one is failing in places where 'wait until located' does not. Why?

Answer (score 3):

As your question is the difference between `wait(until.elementLocated(element, timeout))` and `wait(until.elementVisible(element, timeout))` and you haven't tagged any Selenium binding, I will explain it from a Java perspective.

- `until.elementLocated()` is equivalent to `presenceOfElementLocated()` in Java. It checks that an element is *present* within the HTML DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is *visible*. So there's no guarantee that it's *interactable*.
- `until.elementVisible()` is equivalent to `visibilityOfElementLocated()` in Java. It checks that an element is present within the HTML DOM of a page and is *visible*. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is *greater than 0*. Again this does not necessarily mean that the element is *interactable*, i.e. *clickable*.

For more details on `ExpectedConditions` in Java, see [the docs](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Wait until visible does exactly that. It waits until the element is visible. An element can be in the DOM but be hidden. In that case, it would be able to be located but not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Both until.elementLocated(element, timeout) and until.elementVisible(element, timeout) are used to get the element.

But I would guess that elementLocated will be faster because it's just check that an element is present on the DOM of a page and not necessarily mean that the element is visible. while the elementVisible has to check that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width.

Hope this will explain the difference.